# finding an exact match using RegEx in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm searching for exact course codes in a text. Codes look like this

```
MAT1051
CMP1401*
PHY1001*
MAT1041*
ENG1003*
```

So 3 or 4 uppercase letters followed by 4 digits.

I only want ones that do not end with "*" symbol.

I have tried

```
course_code = re.compile('[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{4}|[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}')
```

which is probably one of the worse ways to do it but kinda works as I can get all the courses listed above. The issue is I don't want those 3 course codes ending with a "*" (failed courses have a * next to their codes) to be included in the list.

I tried adding \w or $ to the end of the expression. Whichever I add, the code returns an empty list.

Comment: You could try adding the pattern `[^\*]` at the end so you would have `[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{4}|[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}[^\*]`

Comment: @taxevader `[^\*]` will only be part of the second case. Just use `{3, 4}` to combine both patterns

Comment: @DeepSpace hmm you're right, so the pattern would be `[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{4}[^\*]|[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}[^\*]` or maybe `[A-Z]{3,4}[0-9]{4}{0,}[^\*]` instead or the cleaner version in the answer

Comment: @taxevader actually that seems to be exactly what I was looking for. However this time the results look like 'MAT1051\n' so I will look up a way to strip that last bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your requirements correctly, you want this pattern:

```
^[A-Z]{3,4}[0-9]{4}$
```

This assumes that you would be searching your entire text stored in a Python string using regex in multiline mode, q.v. this demo:

```py
inp = """MAT1051
CMP1401*
PHY1001*
MAT1041*
ENG1003*"""

matches = re.findall(r'^[A-Z]{3,4}[0-9]{4}$', inp, flags=re.M)
print(matches)  # ['MAT1051']
```

Comment: only works when I don't include ^ or $. tried it as a raw string too. any idea what may cause the problem?

Comment: My code is in fact working with the sample data you provided, assuming you do a search of the entire text in multiline mode.  Are you doing all these things, or something else?

Comment: given code solved my problem. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
# Add a "$" at the end of the re.
# It requires the match to end after the 4 digits.
course_code = re.compile('[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{4}$|[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}$')

# No match here
m = re.match(course_code, "MAT1051*")
print(m)
# This matches
m = re.match(course_code, "MAT1051")
print(m)
```